# Unable to execute Ajax in Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I am trying to Execute Ajax in **Yii**. 
But gives me error as :

> Empty string passed to getElementById()

Below is my code of AJAX :

```
 $url1 = Yii::$app->homeUrl;
    $crurl = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$url1;
      $this->registerJs('$(document).ready(function(){    
        $(".glyphicon.glyphicon-eye-closed").click(function(){
               $.ajax({
                  url: "'.$crurl.'?r=history/move",
                  type: "post",
                  data: {id: this.id},
                  success: function(data){
                            alert(data);
                   }
                 });
        });
});
```

Comment: Can you post the entire error? There should be a line below the error saying what file the error is coming from.

Comment: Here it is:  Empty string passed to getElementById().
jquery.js:2891:12

Comment: the element you're trying to get id of (`$(".glyphicon.glyphicon-eye-closed")`) does not have an id property. `this.id` is returning the empty string

Comment: are you using jquery mobile ?

Comment: @csminb - There is an id attribute. I works when I just check it on alert but in ajax I get the same error. Here is code : return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-closed" id="'.$model->id.'"></span>', $crUrl, [
                                    Yii::t('app', 'history')
                            ]);

Comment: @ Muhammad Omer Aslam- I am directly using Yii. So default jquery it must be using.

Comment: @vikesh are you sure the error at this line? Just remove this code and check, the error is still coming or not.

Comment: @Serhat - which line of code you want me to remember?

Comment: maybe `this` is outside it's context?

Comment: @Sfili- No, I can access it using alert function, but after writing the AJAX function, its not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following options;

1. Check the html code that the `.glyphicon.glyphicon-eye-closed` classes has that has id attr?
2. Replace `this.id` to `$(this).attr('id')`;